# How do I support delete with Windows Cloud Sync Engine API?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, cloud

I am implementing a cloud provider for Windows 10 based off of the [CloudMirror sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror). The problem is that sample does not show how to modify files in the cloud. My app is receiving the delete callbacks: CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE, CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE_COMPLETION. When I run the app and try deleting a file in Windows Explorer, I see the notify delete called three times. Then the notify delete completion once. At some point I need to try deleting the cloud file and report back any failures.

1. Why is the delete callback running three times?
2. When am I supposed to actually delete the file in the cloud?
3. I also noticed that the CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_FILE_CLOSE_COMPLETION callback has a delete flag parameter. Can I just use that instead?

I have been looking at Microsoft's documentation for this API, but I haven't found any explanation on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE is called more than one time because the platform "thinks" that the previous call did not complete successfully. In your CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE callback, you need to call CfExecute() with  CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS.ACKDELETE with CompletionStatus set to STATUS_SUCCESS.

Typically you will delete the cloud file inside CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE, not in CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE_COMPLETION. Because you need to return the result of the file deletion (success, failure, or some custom message) to the system, via CfExecute() call.

Also, note that files are often moved into the recycle bin. So you will get a move call in addition to a delete call.